# WebView in my Android App is loading too slow

Tags: java, android, webview

I am beginner in android app develeopment. My issue is `WebView` in my Android App is loading slowly. Please help me in fixing this issue and my `splash screen` is also loading slowly.

Here is the source of Activity :

```
package com.example.tech2dsk.tech2dsk;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://tech2dsk.blogspot.in/");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new com.example.tech2dsk.tech2dsk.MyAppWebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //hide loading image
                findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //show webview
                findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }});


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        /** Inflating the current activity's menu with res/menu/items.xml */
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        /** Getting the actionprovider associated with the menu item whose id is share */
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.share).getActionProvider();

        /** Setting a share intent */
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    /** Returns a share intent */
    private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Convert Website to Android Application");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT," Vist www.AndroidWebViewApp.com if you Want to Convert your Website or Blog to Android Application");
        return intent;

    }


}
```

Comment: try to use webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);

Comment: Use [crosswalk](https://diego.org/2015/01/07/embedding-crosswalk-in-android-studio/). Its pretty fast than the default webview.

Comment: @NiravRanpara may i know where to implement this code webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);

Comment: @NiravRanpara thanx and my splash screen also loading slow

Comment: but  webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
is deprecated